# How to know the parent class of the invoked java program?

Tags: java, parent-child

I am working on a distributed application and getting an exception in the main method of a class. How do I know which java program has invoked it ? I tried debugging the distributed application, but could not figure it out.

Comment: what about the stack trace? what do you mean, parent class of invoked program?

Comment: Need more details, is this an RMI application?

Comment: It's not RMI call, just invoking a java application.

Comment: If it's just invoking the application you should see the who calls the method in the stacktrace. Otherwise this is really strange.

Comment: Care to post the stack trace? The only instance I can clearly recall when caller information wasn't available from the stack trace was when the class was running in its own thread (hence, the stack trace would generally end at the thread level with no indication of who started the thread and where).

Comment: Below is the stack trace. I would like to know who invoked the YarnChild

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomWriter$RandomMapper
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1179)
..
..
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:143)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.examples.RandomWriter$RandomMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
..
..
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1177)
... 8 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say Java Class A invokes Java Class B (like "java classB") . I am getting the exception in class B. How do I want to know which class has invoked "java classB"?

You cannot know what invoked the java process from ClassB. The Exception will only go as deep as it's own call stack from it's process. If something else started the process, even if it was java itself, there is no way of know this from ClassB.

You are better off using helpful logging (of both debug/info messages and exception stacktraces) from ClassA. You will have to make sure that ClassB exits appropriately when it fails (exit with a code other than 0) and then ClassA can see this failure in the process it spawned.

Comment: Thanks Gweebz - I had spent some time putting break points, printf in the code and could not figure it out. So, wanted to find if this can be figured out from Class B.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the current stacktrace and see who calls your main method.

```
StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Comment: I got the stack trace, but it's not showing the parent class. Let's say Java Class A invokes Java Class B (like "java classB") . I am getting the exception in class B. How do I want to know which class has invoked "java classB"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Javadoc for "Exception":

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

There are several things you can do with the exception object besides call "getMessage()".  For example, you can "printStackTrace()" (showing you how it was called, and where it was thrown).

Comment: I got the stack trace, but it's not showing the parent class. Let's say Java Class A invokes Java Class B (like "java classB") . I am getting the exception in class B. How do I want to know which class has invoked "java classB"?